# Screen flickering - Blackscreen

Tags: drivers, graphics, amdgpu, flicker, msi

**Processor** - I5 2500k 3.3ghz
**Gpu** - MSI Radeon R9 390 8gb
**RAM** - 2 x 1600mhz corsair 8gb

new to linux since my windows crashed..
so i dont really know if it is a drivers problems or not...
i can play the most games at ultra settings when running through my graphics card.. but it will flicker and after a while just go black over the whole screen, i tried removing my graphics card and felt that it was hot to the touch... rebooted and flickering was gone.. and no blackscreens ofc.. so can someone help me to (probably) find drivers?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to that is to reinstall, and while the installation process, make sure to check the box "Install third-party drivers for sound and others" so your drivers will work again with your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Well i checked the box during install so there shouldnt really be a problem

Comment: Weird. Then do a reinstall or use an another Ubuntu flavour.